# Listview items in Dialog not aligning

Tags: android, listview

I'm currently creating a project where a dialog will pop-up and display a list of customers, but I'm having a problem arranging the items inside the **ListView**

here is what's it looks like. Why does it disarrange is there anything missing in my code?

[When Dialog popsup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plvad.jpg)

but it arranges when I focus on the EditText

here is my code in **displaying the dialog**

```
    private void loadAgents(){
        try{
            Dialog dlg=new Dialog(LoginActivity.this);
            dlg.setContentView(R.layout.activity_clients);
            final ListView lvw=dlg.findViewById(R.id.lvw);
            final EditText txtSearch=dlg.findViewById(R.id.txtClient);

            dlg.show();

            initAgents(lvw,"");
            lvw.invalidate();
            lvw.invalidateViews();
            txtSearch.requestFocus();
            lvw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                            .setTitle(LoginActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to set this agent as default agent?")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Cursor c=(Cursor)lvw.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                                    setAgent(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("client")));
                                    initDefaultAgent();
                                    new GetStatus().execute();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // do nothing
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                }
            });
            txtSearch.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                        initAgents(lvw,txtSearch.getText().toString());
                        return  true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            CUF.displaydlgError(LoginActivity.this,"Exception Caught(loadAgents)",ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

here is my code in **filling up the ListView**

```
 private void initAgents(ListView lvw, String str){
        try{
            String filter="";
            if(!str.equals("")){
                filter=" and (clientname like '%"+str+"%' or client like '%"+str+"')";
            }
            String strSQL="select '' as _id, client,clientname,address from client where isagent=1 " +filter + " order by clientname";
            Cursor c=db.SelectQuery(strSQL);
            if(c!=null){
                String[] from={"client","clientname"};
                int[] to={R.id.col1,R.id.col2};
                SimpleCursorAdapter sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(LoginActivity.this,R.layout.lvw_2col,c,from,to,1);
                lvw.setAdapter(sca);
            }else{
                lvw.setAdapter(null);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            CUF.displaydlgError(LoginActivity.this,"Exception Caught(initAgents)",ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

here is my XML layout for the **dialog**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        android:hint="Search Customer"
        android:background="@drawable/border_black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/txtClient"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvw"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my XML for **ListView Items**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/col1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/col2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh I want it to align properly even without focusing on the edittext